# how can I turn my if else to a ternary

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to turn my if else statement into a ternary

```
    if (val === true && optval === 'car')view_list.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      else view_list.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
view_list.style.visibility = (val === true && optval === 'car') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
```

In a ternary statement, you have a few different parts:

`var` = `expression` ? `value_if_true` : `value_if_false`

- `var` is optional. You don't *have* to include it if you don't want to worry about assignment, but in general this is what ternaries are most often used for.
- `expression` is the expression to evaluate. Its boolean evaluation is stored for the next part.
- `value_if_true` is used if `statement` is truthy.
- `value_if_false` is used if `statement` is falsey.

Comment: Nit-pick: The first operand of `?:` is meant to be an expression (i.e. something that yields a value), not a statement. For example, a switch statement can't be the first operand of `?:`.

Comment: I like the way you use words. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

do:

```
view_list.style.visibility = (val === true && optval === 'car') ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

See [Conditional Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification:** If `val` has to be `Boolean` and `true`, then as mentioned in previous posts, `val === true` should be used. On the other hand, if it is only checked for `true` or `false`, then the following simpler version can be used.

```
view_list.style.visibility = (val && optval === 'car') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
```

Good luck
:)

Comment: No it cannot. `if(val)` and `if(val === true)` are *completely* different. Now if you're certain that `val` is strictly a boolean, yes, this is correct, but in general, no.

Comment: Can you explain, please? if(val) statement is only true if val is true

Comment: `if(1)` is `true`, but `1` is certainly not `true`. This is the big difference between `==` and `===`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the type casting and the difference between == & === but in above ternary, it doesnt appear to make a difference.

Comment: PS. It appeared to me that the user wasn't looking to verify if val is boolean and true for that purpose (style.visibility).